# Update default solution and export using CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I want to update `Default solution CRM 2016` and export. How can do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to modify the *default solution* ?. It is a good practice to do your customization in a seperate solution with its own publisher.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the default solution by going to Settings -> Customizations -> Customize the System. Basic solution instructions are here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531198.aspx#BKMK_UsingDefaultSolution

The default solution has the same guid from org to org, so the URL to your default solution will look like this: https://YOURORGNAME.YOURREGION.dynamics.com/tools/solution/edit.aspx?id={fd140aaf-4df4-11dd-bd17-0019b9312238} (just update the host name and region). I usually save a bookmark to my default solution for quick access.